# Extract Via header branch token from SIP message with regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract `branch=z9hG4bKlmrltg10b801lgkf0681.1` from the `Via:` header of a SIP message. Here is the PHP code I have tried:

```
preg_match('/.branch=.* + From:/', $msg, $result)
```

And here is the value of `$msg`:

```
"INVITE sip:3310094@mediastream.voip.cabletel.net:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.50.240:5060;branch=z9hG4bKlmrltg10b801lgkf0681.1
From: DEATON JEANETTE<sip:9123840782@mediastream.voip.cabletel.net:5060>;tag=SDg7j0c01-959bf958-d8f0f4ea-13c4-50029-140b-4d106390-140b"
```

How can I correct my regex to make this work?

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: trying to extract branch=z9hG4bKlmrltg10b801lgkf0681.1 from $msg.Updated dat in question

Comment: updated question have a look

Comment: reason for down vote?

Comment: This question's title is pretty bad. Questioneer, you should update it to better match what you're trying to do. Saying "Regex not working in PHP" is actually a false statement and could refer to other things than a faulty regular expression (like installation failures or other). This may also be the reason for your down-vote.

Answer (score 2):

Please parse your SIP messages properly. I find it highly unlikely that you only want the branch ID, you almost certainly want other information about the transaction other than a pseudo-call ID. SIP messages follow a standardised message format used by several other protocols (including HTTP ;-) ) and there are several libraries out there designed for parsing this message format.

To demonstrate how relatively simple and considerably more powerful this is, lets first take a look at the RFC822 message parser classes that I wrote some time ago (although they have been recently improved and updated). These can be used for parsing emails, I also have a few simple HTTP message parser classes that extend from these:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class representing the basic RFC822 message format
 *
 * @author  Chris Wright
 * @version 1.1
 */
class RFC822Message
{
    /**
     * @var array Collection of headers from the message
     */
    protected $headers = array();

    /**
     * @var string The message body
     */
    protected $body;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param array  $headers Collection of headers from the message
     * @param string $body    The message body
     */
    public function __construct($headers, $body)
    {
        $this->headers = $headers;
        $this->body    = $body;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of a header from the message
     *
     * @param string $name The name of the header
     *
     * @return array The value(s) of the header from the request
     */
    public function getHeader($name)
    {
        $name = strtolower(trim($name));

        return isset($this->headers[$name]) ? $this->headers[$name] : null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the message body
     *
     * @return string The message body
     */
    public function getBody()
    {
        return $this->body;
    }
}

/**
 * Factory which makes RFC822 message objects
 *
 * @author  Chris Wright
 * @version 1.1
 */
class RFC822MessageFactory
{
    /**
     * Create a new RFC822 message object
     *
     * @param array  $headers The request headers
     * @param string $body    The request body
     */
    public function create($headers, $body)
    {
        return new RFC822Message($headers, $body);
    }
}


/**
 * Parser which creates RFC822 message objects from strings
 *
 * @author  Chris Wright
 * @version 1.2
 */
class RFC822MessageParser
{
    /**
     * @var RFC822MessageFactory Factory which makes RFC822 message objects
     */
    protected $messageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param RFC822MessageFactory $messageFactory Factory which makes RFC822 message objects
     */
    public function __construct(RFC822MessageFactory $messageFactory)
    {
        $this->messageFactory  = $messageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Split a message into head and body sections
     *
     * @param string $message The message string
     *
     * @return array Head at index 0, body at index 1
     */
    protected function splitHeadFromBody($message)
    {
        $parts = preg_split('/\r?\n\r?\n/', ltrim($message), 2);

        return array(
            $parts[0],
            isset($parts[1]) ? $parts[1] : null
        );
    }

    /**
     * Parse the header section into a normalized array
     *
     * @param string $head The message head section
     *
     * @return array The parsed headers
     */
    protected function parseHeaders($head)
    {
        $expr =
        '!
          ^
          ([^()<>@,;:\\"/[\]?={} \t]+)          # Header name
          [ \t]*:[ \t]*
          (
            (?:
              (?:                               # First line of value
                (?:"(?:[^"\\\\]|\\\\.)*"|\S+)   # Quoted string or unquoted token
                [ \t]*                          # LWS
              )*
              (?:                               # Folded lines
                \r?\n
                [ \t]+                          # ...must begin with LWS
                (?:
                  (?:"(?:[^"\\\\]|\\\\.)*"|\S+) # ...followed by quoted string or unquoted tokens
                  [ \t]*                        # ...and maybe some more LWS
                )*
              )*
            )?
          )
          \r?$
        !smx';
        preg_match_all($expr, $head, $matches);

        $headers = array();
        for ($i = 0; isset($matches[0][$i]); $i++) {
            $name = strtolower($matches[1][$i]);
            if (!isset($headers[$name])) {
                $headers[$name] = array();
            }

            $value = preg_replace('/\s+("(?:[^"\\\\]|\\\\.)*"|\S+)/s', ' $1', $matches[2][$i]);

            $headers[$name][] = $value;
        }

        return $headers;
    }

    /**
     * Create a message object from a string
     *
     * @param string $message The message string
     *
     * @return RFC822Message The parsed message object
     */
    public function parseMessage($message)
    {
        list($head, $body) = $this->splitHeadFromBody($message);
        $headers = $this->parseHeaders($head);

        return $this->requestFactory->create($headers, $body);
    }
}
```

Nothing particularly scary there if you ignore the terrifying regex for parsing the headers :-P - seriously though, these classes can be used unmodified for parsing the header sections of emails, the basis of RFC822 formatted messages.

SIP models itself on HTTP, so with a couple of fairly simple modifications to the HTTP message parsing classes we can easily adapt them to SIP. Let's take a look at those - in these classes I have (more or less) done a search for `HTTP` and replaced it with `SIP`:

```
<?php

/**
 * Abstract class representing a SIP message
 *
 * @author  Chris Wright
 * @version 1.0
 */
abstract class SIPMessage extends RFC822Message
{
    /**
     * @var string The message protocol version
     */
    protected $version;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param array  $headers Collection of headers from the message
     * @param string $body    The message body
     * @param string $version The message protocol version
     */
    public function __construct($headers, $body, $version)
    {
        parent::__construct($headers, $body);
        $this->version = $version;
    }

    /**
     * Get the message protocol version
     *
     * @return string The message protocol version
     */
    public function getVersion()
    {
        return $this->version;
    }
}

/**
 * Class representing a SIP request message
 *
 * @author  Chris Wright
 * @version 1.0
 */
class SIPRequest extends SIPMessage
{
    /**
     * @var string The request method
     */
    private $method;

    /**
     * @var string The request URI
     */
    private $uri;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param array  $headers The request headers
     * @param string $body    The request body
     * @param string $version The request protocol version
     * @param string $method  The request method
     * @param string $uri     The request URI
     */
    public function __construct($headers, $body, $version, $method, $uri)
    {
        parent::__construct($headers, $body, $version);
        $this->method  = $method;
        $this->uri     = $uri;
    }

    /**
     * Get the request method
     *
     * @return string The request method
     */
    public function getMethod()
    {
        return $this->method;
    }

    /**
     * Get the request URI
     *
     * @return string The request URI
     */
    public function getURI()
    {
        return $this->uri;
    }
}

/**
 * Class representing a SIP response message
 *
 * @author  Chris Wright
 * @version 1.0
 */
class SIPResponse extends SIPMessage
{
    /**
     * @var int The response code
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @var string The response message
     */
    private $message;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param array  $headers The request headers
     * @param string $body    The request body
     * @param string $version The request protocol version
     * @param int    $code    The response code
     * @param string $message The response message
     */
    public function __construct($headers, $body, $version, $code, $message)
    {
        parent::__construct($headers, $body, $version);
        $this->code    = $code;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the response code
     *
     * @return int The response code
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * Get the response message
     *
     * @return string The response message
     */
    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }
}

/**
 * Factory which makes SIP request objects
 *
 * @author  Chris Wright
 * @version 1.0
 */
class SIPRequestFactory extends RFC822MessageFactory
{
    /**
     * Create a new SIP request object
     *
     * The last 3 arguments of this method are only optional  to prevent PHP from triggering
     * an E_STRICT at compile time. IMO this particular error is itself an error on the part
     * of the PHP designers,  and I don't feel bad  about about this workaround,  even if it
     * does mean the signature is technically wrong. It is the lesser of two evils.
     *
     * @param array  $headers The request headers
     * @param string $body    The request body
     * @param string $version The request protocol version
     * @param string $method  The request method
     * @param string $uri     The request URI
     */
    public function create($headers, $body, $version = null, $method = null, $uri = null)
    {
        return new SIPRequest($headers, $body, $version, $method, $uri);
    }
}

/**
 * Factory which makes SIP response objects
 *
 * @author  Chris Wright
 * @version 1.0
 */
class SIPResponseFactory extends RFC822MessageFactory
{
    /**
     * Create a new SIP response object
     *
     * The last 3 arguments of this method are only optional  to prevent PHP from triggering
     * an E_STRICT at compile time. IMO this particular error is itself an error on the part
     * of the PHP designers,  and I don't feel bad  about about this workaround,  even if it
     * does mean the signature is technically wrong. It is the lesser of two evils.
     *
     * @param array  $headers The response headers
     * @param string $body    The response body
     * @param string $version The response protocol version
     * @param int    $code    The response code
     * @param string $message The response message
     */
    public function create($headers, $body, $version = null, $code = null, $message = null)
    {
        return new SIPResponse($headers, $body, $version, $code, $message);
    }
}

/**
 * Parser which creates SIP message objects from strings
 *
 * @author  Chris Wright
 * @version 1.0
 */
class SIPMessageParser extends RFC822MessageParser
{
    /**
     * @var SIPRequestFactory Factory which makes SIP request objects
     */
    private $requestFactory;

    /**
     * @var SIPResponseFactory Factory which makes SIP response objects
     */
    private $responseFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param SIPRequestFactory  $requestFactory  Factory which makes SIP request objects
     * @param SIPResponseFactory $responseFactory Factory which makes SIP response objects
     */
    public function __construct(SIPRequestFactory $requestFactory, SIPResponseFactory $responseFactory)
    {
        $this->requestFactory  = $requestFactory;
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Remove the request line from the message and parse into tokens
     *
     * @param string $head The message head section
     *
     * @return array The parsed request line at index 0, the remainder of the message at index 1
     *
     * @throws \DomainException When the request line of the message is invalid
     */
    private function removeAndParseRequestLine($head)
    {
        // Note: this method  forgives a couple of minor standards violations, mostly for benefit
        // of some older  Polycom phones and for Voispeed,  who seem to make  stuff up as they go
        // along.  It also  treats the  whole line as  case-insensitive  even though  methods are
        // officially case-sensitive,  because having two different casings of the same verb mean
        // different things makes no sense semantically or implementationally.
        // Side note, from RFC3261:
        // > The SIP-Version string is case-insensitive, but implementations MUST send upper-case
        // Wat. Go home Rosenberg, et. al., you're drunk.

        $parts = preg_split('/\r?\n/', $head, 2);

        $expr =
          '@^
            (?:
              ([^\r\n \t]+) [ \t]+ ([^\r\n \t]+) [ \t]+ SIP/(\d+\.\d+) # request
             |
              SIP/(\d+\.\d+) [ \t]+ (\d+) [ \t]+ ([^\r\n]+)            # response
            )
           $@ix';
        if (!preg_match($expr, $parts[0], $match)) {
            throw new \DomainException('Request-Line of the message is invalid');
        }

        if (empty($match[4])) { // request
            $requestLine = array(
                'method'  => strtoupper($match[1]),
                'uri'     => $match[2],
                'version' => $match[3]
            );
        } else { // response
            $requestLine = array(
                'version' => $match[4],
                'code'    => (int) $match[5],
                'message' => $match[6]
            );
        }

        return array(
            $requestLine,
            isset($parts[1]) ? $parts[1] : ''
        );
    }

    /**
     * Create the appropriate message object from a string
     *
     * @param string $message The message string
     *
     * @return SIPRequest|SIPResponse The parsed message object
     *
     * @throws \DomainException When the message string is not valid SIP message
     */
    public function parseMessage($message)
    {
        list($head, $body) = $this->splitHeadFromBody($message);
        list($requestLine, $head) = $this->removeAndParseRequestLine($head);
        $headers = $this->parseHeaders($head);

        if (isset($requestLine['uri'])) {
            return $this->requestFactory->create(
                $headers,
                $body,
                $requestLine['version'],
                $requestLine['method'],
                $requestLine['uri']
            );
        } else {
            return $this->responseFactory->create(
                $headers,
                $body,
                $requestLine['version'],
                $requestLine['code'],
                $requestLine['message']
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Seems like a lot of code just for extracting one header value, doesn't it? Well, it is. But that's not *just* what it does. It parses the whole message into a data structure that provides easy access to any number of bits of information, allowing for (more or less) anything that the standards can throw at you.

So, lets take a look at how you would actually use it:

```
// First we create a parser object
$messageParser = new SIPMessageParser(
  new SIPRequestFactory,
  new SIPResponseFactory
);

// Parse the message into an object
try {
  $message = $messageParser->parseMessage($msg);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // The message parsing failed, handle the error here
}

// Get the value of the Via: header
$via = $message->getHeader('Via');

// SIP is irritatingly non-specific about the format of branch IDs. This
// expression matches either a quoted string or an unquoted token, which is
// about all that you can say for sure about arbitrary implementations.
$expr = '/branch=(?:"((?:[^"\\\\]|\\\\.)*)"|(.+?)(?:\s|;|$))/i';

// NB: this assumes the message has a single Via: header and a single branch ID.
// In reality this is rarely the case for messages that are received, although
// it is usually the case for messages before they are sent.
if (!preg_match($expr, $via[0], $matches)) {
  // The Via: header does not contain a branch ID, handle this error
}

$branchId = !empty($matches[2]) ? $matches[2] : $matches[1];

var_dump($branchId);
```

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iN2KAT)

This answer is almost certainly massively overkill for the problem at hand. However, I would regard it as the *right* way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str = "INVITE sip:3310094@mediastream.voip.cabletel.net:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.50.240:5060;branch=z9hG4bKlmrltg10b801lgkf0681.1
From: DEATON JEANETTE<sip:9123840782@mediastream.voip.cabletel.net:5060>;tag=SDg7j0c01-959bf958-d8f0f4ea-13c4-50029-140b-4d106390-140b";

preg_match('/branch=(.*)From:/i', $str, $output);
print_r( $output );
```

Comment: Its including the From part but i dont want that.I want only the branch value

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/branch=.*/i', $msg, $result);
print_r($result);
```

Will yield something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => branch=z9hG4bKlmrltg10b801lgkf0681.1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex. It checks if there's a space or newline after the `branch` code. The result you want is always stored in `$output[0]`

```
$str = "INVITE sip:3310094@mediastream.voip.cabletel.net:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.50.240:5060;branch=z9hG4bKlmrltg10b801lgkf0681.1 From: DEATON JEANETTE<sip:9123840782@mediastream.voip.cabletel.net:5060>;tag=SDg7j0c01-959bf958-d8f0f4ea-13c4-50029-140b-4d106390-140b";

preg_match('/(branch=.*)( |\r\n)/', $str, $output);
print_r( $output ); // $output[0] is what you need
```

Example:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/Gj0lWD

Answer (score 0):

You can use a look-ahead assertion like this:

```
preg_match_all('/.branch=(.*?)(?=^\S|\Z)/sm', $msg, $matches);
```

*Here, `(?=^\S|\Z)` asserts a new line followed by a non-space (aka folding header) or end-of-subject. This is where the match should end.*

Or just match `branch=` until the end of line:

```
preg_match_all('/.branch=(.*)/m', $msg, $matches);
```

*Works for headers that are not folded.*

See also: [Basic rules of HTTP headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.2)

Comment: Header folding doesn't really matter here, if you folded the branch name/value pair you would break the semantic meaning of the token

Comment: In case you are interested in the massively-overkill approach to this problem (including taking folded headers into account), I have added an answer ;-)